Migrating Mariadb to Mysqldb data using mariadb-dump for Generated always virtual column,
I am trying to migrate the mariadb database to mysql database. I used mariadb-dump and in my database table I have one table which has generated virtual column. So while dumping the data in mariadb the virtual data is dumped in insert query. So after import that dump in mysqldb I am getting
below error,
Example :
Below thing is available in dump sql file from mariadb dump.
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `uuid` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
   `id` int(2),
  `id2` int(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('id'+3) virtual
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii;

insert into test("869482fa-7f5a-4925-be5e-d62484d74d9a", 1, 4),(869482fa-7f5a-4925-be5e-d626484d4d9a", 3,6);

Below error is from mysqldb import,

ERROR 3105 (HY000) at line 113: The value specified for generated column 'id2' in table 'test' is not allowed.

I want the mariadb dump file without the virtual data in insert query I mean dump file should have
Insert into test(uuid, id) values ("869482fa-7f5a-4925-be5e-d62484d74d9a", 1),(869482fa-7f5a-4925-be5e-d626484d4d9a", 3)

Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Please share more details, like the query that causes the problem and your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, please check the tagging of your question

What version of mysql?  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79148

It is mariadb 10.6 and mysql 8.0

Why have you tagged 10.3 and 10.4 but say 10.6 in comments? You could try using mysqldump (the MySQL version), but you may hit other incompatibilities, as the two RDBMS have diverged a lot over the last 15 years. Alternatively, you could drop the virtual columns before dumping the database, and then add them back in after importing to MySQL.

This is currently a bug/feature request (MDEV-32362).
In the mean time you can remove the "GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('id'+3) virtual" definition from the table definition, restore, and then ALTER TABLE to add the generated column back.
Taking two dumps, one with --no-create-info and the other with --no-data might be an easy way to have a dump of table structures that is easier to edit.
